# How to compare python datetime object representing 'UTC-04:00' time with current UTC time

Tags: python, datetime, utc, python-3.8

I am working on a project where I have to find the next 10 trains departing from a station. Below is the api where in I will get the trains data and the time of departure is specified in UTC-04:00 format.

https://api-v3.mbta.com/predictions?filter%5Bstop%5D=place-pktrm&include=route&sort=departure_time

For this I have to compare the current time with departure time and have to find the time difference.

Below is the approach I used to get the time difference but not sure if it is correct. I am new to this and please help me.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime,timezone
#departure time of train in 'UTC-04:00'
>>> time =  "2021-08-21T13:17:47-04:00"
#converting to datetime object with tzinfo
>>> actual_time = datetime.fromisoformat(time)
>>> actual_time
datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 21, 13, 17, 47, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)))
#saving the datetime object representing the current utc time
>>> utc_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
>>> utc_time
datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 21, 20, 18, 32, 694983, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
#converting datetime object with departure time to local time zone 
>>> actual_time_in_local_timezone = actual_time.astimezone(tz=None)
>>> actual_time_in_local_timezone
datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 21, 22, 47, 47, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=19800), 'India Standard Time'))
#converting datetime object with current UTC time to local time zone
>>> utc_time_in_local_timezone = utc_time.astimezone(tz=None)
>>> utc_time_in_local_timezone
datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 22, 1, 48, 32, 694983, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=19800), 'India Standard Time'))
#total seconds difference between both the times
>>> total_seconds_difference = (actual_time_in_local_timezone - utc_time_in_local_timezone).total_seconds()
>>> total_seconds_difference
-10845.694983
```

Comment: Just do `actual_time - utc_time`…‽

Comment: Since you're dealing with *aware* datetime,  the different UTC offsets will be accounted for in timedelta arithmetic. No need to convert to local time.